# PHP grabbing an array from another array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have an array like so

```
Array (
   [0] => Array (
       [64579] => Array (
           [title] => title
           [description] => blah, blah, blah
           [image] => Array (
                [original] => Array ( [src] => image1.jpg )
                [reference] => Array ( [src] => image1_big.jpg )
                [thumb] => Array ( [src] => image1_thumb.jpg )
           )
```

What I am trying to grab is the src of reference image...I have tried the following

```
foreach($images as $row => $value){
               $gallery[] = $value['image'];
}
```

but it returns like so

```
Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => [3] => [4] => [5] => [6] => [7] => [8] => [9] => [10] => [11] => [12] => [13] => [14] => [15] => [16] => [17] => [18] => [19] => [20] => [21] => [22] => [23] => [24] => [25] => [26] => [27] => [28] => [29] => [30] => [31] => [32] => [33] => [34] => [35] => [36] => [37] => [38] => [39] => [40] => [41] => [42] => [43] => [44] => [45] => [46] => [47] => [48] => )
```

What do I have to do to add the reference image src to my new gallery array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is a three dimensional array... you need to wrap this in another loop..

```
foreach($images as $imageGroupList)
    foreach($imageGroupList as $row => $value){
           $gallery[] = $value['image'];
    }
}
```

of if your top level array only ever has a single element you can just iterate of it

```
foreach($images[0] as $row => $value){
       $gallery[] = $value['image'];
}
```